# Trigger menu item

Tags: python, gtk

I made a menu in python with gtk with the following code and it works fine.

```
menu = Gtk.Menu()
myentry = Gtk.MenuItem('mytext')
myentry.connect('activate', self.myfunc)
menu.append(myentry)
menu.show_all()
```

How can i trigger the menu item from my script ?

I want it to have the same effect as if i clicked it manually.

I need something like:

`menu.myentry.trigger()`

I am absolutely new to python.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I think you can use `menu.select_item(myentry)`

Comment: select_item() indeed selects the item, but seems to not trigger it.

Comment: And what about `myentry.activate()`?

Comment: The window does not pop up, but when i close the application, a boundingbox of the desired window flashes for a splitsecond

Comment: Provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That "boundingbox of the desired window" thing sounds like an error in your program structure.